# Need more than one value to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a program that splits a flat file at the '|' symbol and seperates each entity into a new object defined in the code. It looks like this:

```
    results = 0
    searchphrase = input("Search: ")
    with open('file.dat', 'r', encoding='utf8') as info_1:
        for line in info_1:
            a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m = line.split('|')
            if searchphrase in a:
                results +=1
                print(results, a + '|' + b + '|' + c etc.)
```

EDIT 1

This is the version of the program that does not work and gives me the error message `need more than 1 value to unpack`, resolving to the `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m = line.split('|')` line.

The format of the data from the file I am calling is as follows:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
```

Is there a reason it would interpret that as a single line and not spread each entity into its own object? The program runs fine when I do it like this:

```
results = 0
searchphrase = input("Search: ")
with open('file.ext', 'r', encoding='utf8') as info_1:
    for line in info_1:
        a = line.split('|')
        if searchphrase in a:
            results +=1
            print(results, a)
```

But I want people to be able to search for information based on specific columns of the file (i.e search a for x, search d for y, etc.). How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Aside: There is a standard-library module specifically designed to aid you with tasks like this: http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html

Comment: Aside: it's unlikely that a line like `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m = something` is the best way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.  Not impossible, but pretty unlikely.  You're far better off using a dict or referring to the columns by indexing into a list or tuple or some combination of those.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have *empty lines* in your input. Skip these:

```
for line in info_1:
    if not line.strip(): continue
```

but you probably want to use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead:

```
import csv

for row in csv.reader(open('file.dat', newlines=''), delimiter='|'):
```

Comment: So with the csv module, how would that change the structure of the code? Do i still need to specify that a, b, c, d, e, f = line.split('|')?

Comment: @ErikG.: You could use `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m = row` if you *have* to.